# Concatenating strings with spaces using Python

Tags: python, concatenation, spaces

When I run this code it behaves like expected:

```
x = int(input("Put number: "))
result_figure =[]
xtempleft = x-1
xtempright = 0
space = " "
sl = "/"
bsl  = "\\"
#Q1
for i in range(x):
    if xtempleft > 0:
        q1= space * xtempleft + sl
        xtempleft -= 1
        print(q1)

    else:
        q1 = sl
        print(q1)
#Q2
for i in range(x):
    if xtempright == 0:
        xtempright += 1
        q2= bsl 
        print(q2)
    else:
        q2 = space * xtempright + bsl
        xtempright += 1
        print(q2)
```

I get this:

```
    /
   /
  /
 /
/
\
 \
  \
   \
    \
```

The problem is that when I try to do some modification:

```
for i in range(x):
    result =""
    if xtempleft > 0:
        q1= space * xtempleft + sl
        xtempleft -= 1
        result += q1     
    else:
        q1 = sl
        result += q1
#Q2
    if xtempright == 0:
        xtempright += 1
        q2= bsl 
        result += q2
    else:
        q2 = space * xtempright + bsl
        xtempright += 1
        result += q2  
    print(result)
```

to print what I need in the same line i get it like spaces from Q2 disappeared somewhere and didn't concatenate.

```
    /\
   / \
  /  \
 /   \
/    \
```

Anyone could help me with this? I have tried in many ways and can't get it.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `/` goes one position left on each line, you need one additional space before the `\`. It is enough to write in Q2:

```
    q2 = space * 2 * xtempright + bsl
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In modification you omitted the for loop.

In your initial code there are two for loops and in your modification you omitted the second for loop.

Comment: Why do you write a for loop when you dont want one? In the first case there are 2*n lines and in second case there are only n lines

Answer (score 0):

If this is your expected output,

```
    /\
   /  \
  /    \
 /      \
/        \
```

Modify #Q2 to :

```
if xtempright == 0:
        xtempright += 1
        q2= bsl 
        result += q2
    else:
        q2 = space * (xtempright+1) + bsl
        xtempright += 2
        result += q2
```